# Tree conditions in VF

Tags: visualforce

I m new in VF and i need some help

I trying to do an email , where the information that will appear in this email it depends from the value of one field, but it can have three possible options, imagine if the field value is equal to one it show on message in the email, if to "2" show anohter and if 3..., how can i manage this with thw visualforce condition.

THANKS YOU VERY MUCH IN ADVANCE

Comment: Are you using visualforce email template or just a visualforce with controller ?One can include logic in controller part as well as logic in view part of visualforce .

Comment: welcome to community !Also could you please tell what have you tried so far

Comment: I m just using the visual force controller,                                                     <p>
         <apex:outputtext value="{!{!Master_Application__c.Scholarship_Decision__c}}" render="{!if(ISNULL({!Master_Application__c.Scholarship_Decision__c}),false,true)}"
         </p>

Comment: please post controller code snippet to assist

Comment: This field schoolarship decision have 4 options ("none", "30","40" "60") , and if its  none in the template needs to appear some text, or if the choose any of the other option (in this case is 30, 40 60) it need to appear a different text

Comment: but also , that field schoolarship it only appear if {!Master_Application__c.Interest_in_Merit_Scholarships__c} is equal to yes

Comment: Mohith its the firts time that i m working with VF so i m completly lost...so thank you for the help

Comment: Thanks no problems .Have answered for you this time and i am sure after an year or so you will be contributing to this site your learning's and answers and grow the community

Answer (score 1):

```
public  class Treeconditionhelper {

  public string displaytext{get;set;}
  public Id urlid;

  public Treeconditionhelper(){

   urlid=Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');  

   //Assuming your query has fetched data here 
    Master_Application__c m=[Select Id,Interest_in_Merit_Scholarships__c,Scholarship_Decision__c from Master_Application__c  where id=:urlid]

      if(m.Scholarship_Decision__c=30 && m.Interest_in_Merit_Scholarships__c){
                 displaytext='text1';
        }else if(m.Scholarship_Decision__c=40 && m.Interest_in_Merit_Scholarships__c){
          displaytext='text2';
       }//..continue the pattern

  }


 }
```

visualforce code

```
<p> <apex:outputtext value="{!displaytext}‌​" </p>
```

The above pattern may help you to achieve what you looking for .I recommend going through visualforce guide and visualforce workbook to gain more expertise

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of the `Case` function.  See [the complete list of visualforce functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) for more information.  Below is an example of using the case function to display either "Display One", "Display Two", or "Display Three" depending on the value of `Master_Application__c.Scholarship_Decision__c`.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!CASE(Master_Application__c.Scholarship_Decision__c, "Value1", "Display One", "Value2", "Display Two", "Default Value")}" />
```